GPO Method to Push DNS Settings to All PCs in a Domain Environment
I am currently facing a challenging task regarding setting DNS configurations for all PCs. I aim to push DNS entries to ensure that all the machines use the correct DNS servers for domain resolution using Group Policy Object.
Methods that were already checked :
Using the Group Policy settings in "Computer Configuration  > Administrative Templates > Network > DNS Client > DNS servers". Set it to "Enable" and add IP Address list. Problem here was that, it was only supported on Windows XP. The changes were not reflected on Windows 10 PC's when we tried.
Setting up Group Policy Object present in "Computer Configuration → Policies → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Network List Manager Policies". As mentioned in the link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1279987/changing-primary-and-secondary-dns-via-gpo). The options informed in this link was not present.
I have already found methods of doing this using a PowerShell and a bat script, but wanted to confirm if such options are available in GPO itself that I may have missed.
Thank you for your assistance.

No, Group Policy isn't for everything. This is a classic textbook example of what your Configuration Management solution is for.

It is already provided by DHCP. Are you afraid people will manually change it afterwards? You can block outbound DNS queries to anything but your own DNS servers so that users who manually put in 8.8.8.8 or something similar, will not be able to resolve anything.

We are currently resorting to use Run-Once registry to run a power-shell script to push DNS to all the PCs in the domain . Thank you all for the helpful suggestions.
